# How to provide Indexing in Excel sheet in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I can easily import my SQL database to excel sheet in PHP. How can I place a INDEX on my sheet that will take me to HOME PAGE of excel sheet?

INDEXINg is possible in excel sheet using PHPEXCEL?

Comment: Do you mean a hyperlink to your web site rather than an index?

Comment: Hyperlink to another excelsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean a hyperlink to your web site:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('E26', 'www.phpexcel.net');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setUrl('http://www.phpexcel.net');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setTooltip('Navigate to website');
```

If you mean hyperlink to another worksheet within the same workbook:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('E26', 'Worksheet XYZ');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setUrl('sheet://'<my destination worksheet name>'!A1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setTooltip('Jump to another worksheet');
```